How to assess a binomial model (ASReml)?
I have fitted the following mixed model with a binomial distribtion using the ASReml package:
mod <- asreml(fixed = Prevalence ~  Sex,
         random = ~ ID, 
         na.action = na.method (x = "include", y = "include"),
         family.asreml = asr_binomial(link = "logit"),
         data = data.df)

I know looking at the residual plots for binomial models are not useful, so I want to know if there is another way to assess how well the model fits my data using the ASReml package?

Can you make this into a reproducible example?
